# Why does my code save files with the server files and not in the uploads folder?

Tags: python, flask

I am new to flask and trying to make my script upload files by the users to an upload folder inside the script folder but when I test the script with a simple file I uploads it to the same path where my script is running and not to the uploads folder

```
upload_path_ = "/uploads"


app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True


app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = upload_path_


@app.route('/upload')
def upload_file():
    return render_template('upload.html')



## uploading files to the server 
@app.route('/uploader' , methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def upload():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.files['file']
        f.save(secure_filename("sth"))

        return "File uploaded successfully "
```

Answer (score 1):

As illustrated in the [Flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/), the `UPLOAD_FOLDER` configuration name does not act as a global settings that will tell Flask to send everything to the directory you've set. It is used as a way to store the information upon your application setup and retrieve it anywhere you need.

So try replacing this line:

```
f.save(secure_filename("sth"))
```

by

```
f.save(os.path.join(app.config['UPLOAD_FOLDER'], "sth"))
```